# Using My Own Classes On Wp Unit Tests

Tags: theme-development, customization, unit-tests

(I'm trying to solve style problems of code samples)

I'm developing a theme but I have some classes which developed for this theme. I want to run unit tests on my theme.

I've followed this steps:

1. Checked out test repo to my root web folder:

   ```
   svn co http://develop.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/ wordpress-develop
   ```
2. Copied my theme folder to *wordpress-develop/src/wp-content/themes*
3. Created an empty database and set up *wp-tests-config.php* file. Also added this line to *wp-tests-config.php*

   ```
   define( 'WP_DEFAULT_THEME', 'THEMENAME' );
   ```
4. Created *wordpress-develop/tests/phpunit/tests/konser.php* file with this content:

   ```
   <?php
   class Test_Konser extends WP_UnitTestCase {

   public function test_firstTest(){
        // Arrange
           $id = $this->factory->post->create(array(
                   'post_type' => 'konser',
               ));
           add_post_meta($id, "konser_tarih", time());
        $ids = get_posts(array(
               'post_type' => 'konser',
               )
           );
        foreach ($ids as $id) {
        $this->assertInstanceOf('WP_Post',$id);
       $ss = get_post_meta($id->ID, "konser_tarih", true);
       $this->assertTrue($ss!='');
       }
   }
   }
   ```

   [image]
5. But I want to use my `Konser` and `PostType` classes.

   ```
   function setUp() {

      $this->post_id = new Konser(410);
      parent::setUp();
   }
   function test_ID() {
       $this->assertInternalType("int", $this->post_id);
   }
   ```
6. Added this 2 lines to */wordpress-develop/tests/phpunit/includes/functions.php*

   ```
     require_once('src/wp-content/themes/THEMENAME/include/PostType.php');
     require_once('src/wp-content/themes/THEMENAME/include/Konser.php');
   ```
7. But I'm getting **Call to undefined function get_post() in konsertv-develop/src/wp-content/themes/THEMENAME/include/PostType.php**

Can you tell me what I'm missing?

CONTENT OF PostType.php

```
  <?php
  class PostType
  {
public $post;
public $ID;

function PostType($ID) {
    $this->post = get_post($ID);
    $this->ID = $ID;
}
function getPost()
{
    return $this->post;
}
function getTarih()
{
    return get_post_meta($this->ID, "konser_tarih", true);
}
function getID()
{
    return $this->ID;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 6 . Added this 2 lines to
>   `/wordpress-develop/tests/phpunit/includes/functions.php`
>
> `require_once('src/wp-content/themes/THEMENAME/include/PostType.php');` 
>   `require_once('src/wp-content/themes/THEMENAME/include/Konser.php');`

That is the problem. The `get_post()` function doesn't exist, becuase the `phpunit/includes/functions.php` file is included before WordPress is loaded. That is actually part of the reason that it exists as a separate file: so it can be included in your own phpunit bootstrap (if you need one, and need to use those functions). For an example of how this is done for plugins, you can see [a tutorial I've written](http://codesymphony.co/writing-wordpress-plugin-unit-tests/#setting-up-your-plugin-for-testing).

However, in your case, you are testing a theme, and your test suite is not complex enough that it warrants its own bootstrap. Actually, your third step, adding `define( 'WP_DEFAULT_THEME', 'THEMENAME' );` to the `wp-tests-config.php` should be sufficient. The two files you're `require`ing will automatically be loaded as part of your theme. (Yes, the theme is loaded during the unit tests.)

So your mistake was step 6. It isn't necessary.

Comment: Now I got it @J.D. Thank you for your detailed response.